# Time in Sharepoint

Tags: development, asp.net, data

We have got two method in Sharepoint to get the time. One is ToUniversalTime() an secound is ToLocalTime() But when we are in server and have got a aplication instaled on server which kind data method is better ? If wee set a ToLocalTime it will take a time from server or from local machine loging to our aplication ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

this is the difference.

ToUniversalTime does:

```
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(this, TimeZoneInfoOptions.NoThrowOnInvalidTime);
```

Instead ToLocalTime does:

```
  if (this.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
    return this;
  bool isDaylightSavings = false;
  bool isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
  long ticks = this.Ticks + TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffsetFromUtc(this, TimeZoneInfo.Local, out isDaylightSavings, out isAmbiguousLocalDst).Ticks;
  if (ticks > 3155378975999999999L)
  {
    if (throwOnOverflow)
      throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_ArgumentOutOfRangeException"));
    else
      return new DateTime(3155378975999999999L, DateTimeKind.Local);
  }
  else
  {
    if (ticks >= 0L)
      return new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousLocalDst);
    if (throwOnOverflow)
      throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_ArgumentOutOfRangeException"));
    else
      return new DateTime(0L, DateTimeKind.Local);
  }
```

So seems that the ToLocalTime function get the datetime from the server

Comment: So we should set all times and data times in ToLocalTime. Not the ToUniversalTime. And If the time changing to the Sammer time it will change if the sammer time changing in Server ?

Comment: I should change in all playces to the ToLocalTimes ? I afraid it will be in about 200 places where I used ToUniversalTime